# enabling nested loop join and disabling hash join in postgres.

Tags: postgresql

I want to disable the hashjoin algorithm used by postgres by default, and enable the nested loop join algorithm, can some one tell me how to do that.

I tried modifying the postgresql.conf file where I set the value enable_hashjoin=off and also enable_mergejoin=off, so that I could force postgres to use nested loop.
but postgres is still using the hash join algorithm even after modifying the postgresql.conf file.

I did try the pg_ctl reload command to reload the configuration files, but its still using the hash join algorithm and not the nested loop algorithm. I even restarted the server, even then its still using the hash join algorithm

can some one tell me what I am doing wrong, or is there any other file where I need to modify to force postgres to use nested loop algorithm.

PS: I already posted this question in pg_hackers mailing list,but I have not got any answer there yet, so I am posting here.

Thanks

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Which problem are you trying to solve? Btw: you typically don't need to to mess around with `postgresql.conf` to change those settings. `set enable_hashjoin=off` before running your SQL should do the same.

Comment: Could you please make sure that the setting has taken effect? F.ex. with `select current_setting('enable_hashjoin')` -- But, describing the *real* problem behind your intent (probably in a different question) could generate a more useful answer to you.

Comment: I wanted to find the time nested loop is taking to join two tables, its part of one of my project.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - thanks set enable_hashjoin=off did work, though I wonder why it didn't work when I modified the file of postgresql.conf, anyways thank you

Comment: If `set enable_hashjoin=off` is working then either your `pg_ctl reload` did not work for some reason, or the new setting did not have an effect on an existing session (not sure about that though).

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-query.html `enable_nestloop (boolean)` is what you need